# ¿como puedo realizar el enviando peticion POST a nodejs con express y postman?

Tags: mysql, json, nodejs, express, postman

Estoy intentando guardar en campo en una tabla mysql por medio de un API con nodejs , Express desde postman. no se si es un error del formato del JSON o de como se esta parseando el body. de que forma se puede hacer esta petición?:
:

Json enviado desde postman(raw, JSON):

```
{
    "namel": "Teusaquillo",
    "area_2m": 6000,
    "parent": "chapinero"
}
```

al enviar la peticion me arroja este Error:

```
<pre>SyntaxError: Unexpected token   in JSON at position 3<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at JSON.parse (&lt;anonymous&gt;)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at parse (<mypaht>\nodeapi\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:89:19)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at <mypaht>\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:121:18<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at invokeCallback (<mypaht>nodeapi\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:224:16)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at done (<mypaht>\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:213:7)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at IncomingMessage.onEnd (<mypaht>\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:273:7)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:326:22)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1252:12)<br> &nbsp`; &nbsp;at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)</pre>
```

otra vista del error

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token   in JSON at position 3
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at parse (<mypaht>\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:89:19)
    at <mypaht>\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:121:18
    at invokeCallback (<mypaht>\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:224:16)
    at done (<mypaht>\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:213:7)
    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (<mypaht>\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:273:7)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:326:22)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1252:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
```

este es el index.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const mysql = require('mysql');
 
app.use(bodyParser.json());
 
//create database connection
const conn = mysql.createConnection({
  ...
});
 
//connect to database
conn.connect((err) =>{
  ...
});
 
//add new locations
app.post('/api/locations',(req, res) => {
  let data = {namel: req.body.namel, area_2m: req.body.area_2m, parent: req.body.parent};  
  let sql = "INSERT INTO location SET ?";
  let query = conn.query(sql, data,(err, results) => {
    if(err) throw err;
    res.send(JSON.stringify({"status": 200, "error": null, "response": results}));
  });
});
```

esta es la tabla de la base de datos:

```
CREATE TABLE `location` (
  `namel` char(100) NOT NULL,
  `area_2m` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `parent` char(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`namel`),
  KEY `parent` (`parent`),
  CONSTRAINT `location_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`parent`) REFERENCES `location` (`namel`)
)
```

de antemano gracias.

Comment: ¿Has depurado lo que recibes en tu controlador? Por ejemplo, ¿qué te muestra lo siguiente: `util.inspect(req.body)`? (Claro debes importar `util` con `const util = require('util');`) O puedes hacerlo con un `console.log(req.body)`.

Comment: Gracias por responder, el console.log(req.body) sale vacio --> {}

Comment: Pues entonces no estás recibiendo los datos, tu consulta SQL fallará irremediablemente. Te sugiero usar `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true});` justo debajo de la linea donde tienes `app.use(bodyParser.json());`. Comenta el resultado.

Comment: @MauricioContreras agregue la linea y continúan sin llegar los datos a node. no llegan ni en POST ni en GET